# The URL is appearing in the place of the website name

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

While running from Android Studio:

[image]

After hosting:

[image]

I want my website name to appear in that place.
So if anyone can help me with this, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the title of MaterialApp. Like this:

```
  MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome - Ajith'
```

Answer (score 3):

Open `lib/web/index.html` and check the `<title></title>` tag content. And also be sure if [title](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/title.html) property of [MaterialApp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html) is also set.